# AlpineJS x-for not running after x-data update

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

I am running into a very strange issue where I have a chatroom that should update whenever a new message is posted. Instead when I add a new message the x-data is getting updated and I can see the message there but the x-for doesnt seem to run and it never appears on the frontend. Then when I enter another message the previous message shows up on the frontend but the latest message does not show even though the x-data has been updated to reflect it.

Here is the code below:

```
<div
    x-data="{{ json_encode(['messages' => $messages, 'messageBody' => '']) }}"
    x-init="
            Echo.join('chat.2')
                .listen('ChatSent', (e) => {
                    @this.call('incomingMessage', e)
                    console.log(e)
                })
            ">
  <div
      class="wow fadeInUp mb-10 rounded-md bg-light-bg dark:bg-dark"
      data-wow-delay="0s"
    >
      <h3
        class="border-b border-body-color border-opacity-10 py-4 px-8 text-lg font-semibold text-black dark:border-white dark:border-opacity-10 dark:text-white"
      >
        Chat
      </h3>
      <div id="chat-window" class="relative w-full p-3 overflow-y-auto h-[14rem]">

              <ul class="space-y-2">
                    <template
                        x-for="message in messages"
                        :key="message.id"
                    >
                      <div>
                        <template x-if="message.user_id == {{ Auth::user()->id }}">
                          <li class="flex justify-end">
                            <div class="relative max-w-xl px-4 py-2 text-black dark:text-white bg-gray-100 dark:bg-black rounded shadow">
                              <span class="block" x-text="message.body"></span>
                            </div>
                          </li>
                        </template>
                        <template x-if="message.user_id != {{ Auth::user()->id }}">
                          <li class="flex justify-start">
                            <div class="relative max-w-xl px-4 py-2 text-black dark:text-white bg-blue-100 dark:bg-[#1e2a78] rounded shadow">
                              <span class="block" x-text="message.body"></span>
                            </div>
                          </li>
                        </template>
                      </div>
                    </template>
              </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="flex items-center justify-between w-full p-3 border-t border-gray-300">
                <input 
                  @keydown.enter="
                      @this.call('sendMessage', messageBody)
                      messageBody = ''
                  "
                  x-model="messageBody"
                  type="text" 
                  placeholder="Message"
                  class="block w-full py-2 pl-4 mx-3 bg-gray-100 dark:bg-black rounded-full outline-none focus:text-gray-700 dark:focus:text-white dark:text-white"
                  name="message" required />
                <button             
                @click="
                    @this.call('sendMessage', messageBody)
                    messageBody = ''
                ">
                  <svg class="w-5 h-5 text-black dark:text-white origin-center transform rotate-90" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                    viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor">
                    <path
                      d="M10.894 2.553a1 1 0 00-1.788 0l-7 14a1 1 0 001.169 1.409l5-1.429A1 1 0 009 15.571V11a1 1 0 112 0v4.571a1 1 0 00.725.962l5 1.428a1 1 0 001.17-1.408l-7-14z" />
                  </svg>
                </button>
              </div>
              @error('messageBody')
                <div class="w-full p-2 text-center">
                  <span class="text-red-500">Message is required!</span>
                </div>
              @enderror
    </div>
    <div
              class="wow fadeInUp mb-10 rounded-md bg-light-bg dark:bg-dark"
              data-wow-delay="0s">
              <h3
                class="border-b border-body-color border-opacity-10 py-4 px-8 text-lg font-semibold text-black dark:border-white dark:border-opacity-10 dark:text-white"
              >
                Active Players
              </h3>
              <ul class="flex flex-wrap py-6 px-8">
                @forelse($here as $authData)
                  <li>
                    <a
                      href="javascript:void(0)"
                      class="text-body-color-3 mr-3 mb-3 inline-flex items-center justify-center rounded-full border-[.5px] border-body-color bg-body-color bg-opacity-10 py-2 px-4 hover:border-primary hover:bg-primary hover:text-white dark:border-[#363D68] dark:bg-[#272E5C] dark:text-white dark:hover:border-primary dark:hover:bg-primary dark:hover:text-white"
                    >
                      {{ $authData['name'] }}
                    </a>
                  </li>
                @empty
                @endforelse
              </ul>
            </div>
</div>
```

I figure it has to be something simple I am missing and hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

EDIT to include Livewire code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use App\Events\ChatSent;
use App\Models\Chat;
use App\Models\Games;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Livewire\Component;

class Chatbox extends Component
{
    public $game_id, $game, $chats;
    public $here = [];
    public $messages = [];

    public function getListeners()
    {
        $game_id = $this->game_id;

        return [
            "echo-presence:chat.{$game_id},here" => 'here',
            "echo-presence:chat.{$game_id},joining" => 'joining',
            "echo-presence:chat.{$game_id},leaving" => 'leaving',
        ];
    }
    public function render()
    {
        return view('games.components.chatbox');
    }

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->game = Games::find($this->game_id);
        $this->messages = Chat::
            where('games_id', $this->game_id)
            ->with('user')
            ->latest()
            ->limit(30)
            ->get()
            ->reverse()
            ->values()
            ->toArray();
    }

    public function sendMessage($body)
    {
        if (! $body) {
            $this->addError('messageBody', 'Message body is required.');
            return;
        }

        $message = Auth::user()->chats()->create([
            'body' => $body,
            'games_id' => $this->game_id,
        ]);

        $message->load('user');

        broadcast(new ChatSent($message, $this->game))->toOthers();
        $myMessage = $message->toArray();

        $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('update-chat');
        array_push($this->messages, $myMessage);
    }

    /**
     * @param $message
     */
    public function incomingMessage($message)
    {
        // get the hydrated model from incoming json/array.
        $message = Chat::with('user')->find($message['id']);
        array_push($this->messages, $message);
        $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('update-chat');
    }

    /**
     * @param $data
     */
    public function here($data)
    {
        $this->here = $data;
    }

    /**
     * @param $data
     */
    public function leaving($data)
    {
        $here = collect($this->here);

        $firstIndex = $here->search(function ($authData) use ($data) {
            return $authData['id'] == $data['id'];
        });

        $here->splice($firstIndex, 1);

        $this->here = $here->toArray();
    }

    /**
     * @param $data
     */
    public function joining($data)
    {
        $this->here[] = $data;
    }

}
```

Comment: How did you confirm that `x-data` has been updated? Did you use e.g. the Alpine.js DevTools extension?

Comment: Hi Dauros, I can see the message data being added in developer tools when I submit the data

Comment: By the log message  `console.log(e)`?  That itself does not guarantee that the `x-data` has been updated as well. Do you have the [Alpine.js devtools](https://github.com/alpine-collective/alpinejs-devtools) installed? You can inspect/update `x-data` directly with it. Furthermore, could you include the relevant backend codes as well?

Comment: Hi Dauros, I am able to see it updated in the Alpine.js DevTools extension. Here is a screenshot of what i am seeing right after adding a message with body "newww" It is populated in the x-data, but the frontend does add the new message. http://markwow.com/x-data-screenshot.png Also I will update the initial post to include the livewire file as well.

Comment: Is your code in a Livewire component completely? If so, what is your reasoning for using an `x-data` with `x-for` over using Livewire PHP iterations? 

Whenever I use `x-data` with `x-for` and I want them to be updated by Alpine, I always add a `wire:ignore` to the `div` carrying the `x-data`, because otherwise it causes weird behaviour in updating the data. I then use a browser event (with data) to add any new data to the looped data: 

`<div x-data="{{ json_encode(['messages' => $messages]) }}" wire:ignore x-on:update-chat.window="messages.push($event.detail);">`

Comment: Hi Yinci, I had built it out this way since Livewire doesnt support listening for events on presence channels, but I actually just looked and I see there is a PR to fix this on their github(https://github.com/livewire/livewire/pull/4772) so I may just rewrite it in the mean time to be handled completely with php iterations and then pull that PR down to handle listening for the incomingMessage event.